# Timedelta error - AttributeError: type object 'datetime.datetime' has no attribute 'timedelta'

Tags: python-3.x, datetime, timedelta

writing a test in the same if not similar format to my main source code and im getting an error on the timedelta function inside datetime module.

in my main source folder the code has no problem recognising the timedelta function

```
`    from datetime import datetime, timedelta

     def test_call_alert_manager(self, m_requests):
            er = EventReceiver({})
            er.alerts = fixture["detail"]["findings"]
            er._username = 'any1'
            er._password = 'any2'
            er.call_am()
            auth = HTTPBasicAuth('any1', 'any2')
            m_requests.assert_called_once_with('URL', json=[{
             'endsAt': (datetime.now() + datetime.timedelta(days=1)).strftime
              ('%Y-%m-         %dT%H:%M:%S.000z'),
       
>           'endsAt': (datetime.now() + datetime.timedelta(days=1)).strftime
             ('%Y-%m%dT%H:%M:%S.000z'),
       E       AttributeError: type object 'datetime.datetime' has no attribute 'timedelta'
`
```

any ideas where im going wrong here

Comment: `datetime.timedelta(days=1)` -> `timedelta(days=1)`. you already imported `timedelta` !